# Android: getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) is not working in Service

Tags: android, activity-manager

I am getting a strange problem which I am not able to understand as the app does not give any crash log or any other message which I can follow to search the problem.

I launching a service from my activity and in this service I am trying to find out the number of process which are in error state but when my code reaches to the line

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
```

then the app stops working. When I debugged my app then I found that after hitting the above line the debugger navigates to the file ActivityThread.java in cleanUpPendingRemoveWindows() with a message "Source code does not match the byte code". I am not able to understand why this is happening?

My code is:

```
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.app.usage.UsageStats;
import android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

public class Senddata_1 extends Service {

String TAG = "uEarn:Senddata_1";

public void find_out_process_in_error_state(){

    List<ActivityManager.ProcessErrorStateInfo> processErrorStateInfos;

    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    processErrorStateInfos = am.getProcessesInErrorState();

    if(processErrorStateInfos != null) {
        for (ActivityManager.ProcessErrorStateInfo pes : processErrorStateInfos) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Process in Error state" + pes.processName);
            Log.e(TAG, "Process error messga" + pes.shortMsg);

            message = message + "<p>Process in Error state:" + pes.processName + ", error message:" + pes.shortMsg + "</p>\n";
        }
    }
    return;
}

 public Senddata_1() {

    // TODO: Get the Filename through the intent

    Log.e(TAG, "Inside service Senddata_1");

    find_out_process_in_error_state();

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
   //        return;
}
}
```

Comment: where do you call this service ? There is no way android getSystemService is not working, maybe you need to add permission or just forgot to call method

Comment: I am calling this service named Senddata_1 from an another activity.

Comment: You should use this method inside onStartCommand not into the constructor. You can not directly call service by creating a new object. In this case, context would be null. Call your service inside the activity like this one:  startService(new Intent(this, Senddata_1 .class));

Comment: Ok, I will try. I am starting my Senddata_1 service like below

Intent Service = new Intent(this, Senddata_1.class);
startService(Service);

Comment: Also write your method inside the onStartCommand method, not the constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the app does not give any crash log or any other message which I can follow to search the problem.

Oh, I strongly suspect that it does.

> when my code reaches to the line... then the app stops working.

That is because you are trying to call methods inherited from `Service` before you call `super.onCreate()` in your `onCreate()` method. The most typical exception will be a `NullPointerException`.

Replace your constructor with:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  find_out_process_in_error_state();
}
```

Then, when you start the service, your `find_out_process_in_error_state()` method will be called, when it should be safe for it to call `getSystemService()`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It did work replacing the constructor as you suggested.